# Request API but return empty, why?

Tags: python, pandas, api, request

searched various method, none working, dont understand which part went wrong.

it works for single time, how to loop through a list of ID, some ID may return error, skipped.

current code

```
x = 22555003
URL = "https://data.gcis.nat.gov.tw/od/data/api/5F64D864-61CB-4D0D-8AD9-492047CC1EA6?$format=json&$filter=Business_Accounting_NO eq {}".format(x)
response = requests.get(url = URL)
data = response.json()
result = pd.DataFrame(data)
result.head()
```

desire output but error

```
listID = ['22555003','12345678','27240313']
#12345678 is error ID
result = []
for x in listID:
    try:
        JSONContent = requests.get("https://data.gcis.nat.gov.tw/od/data/api/5F64D864-61CB-4D0D-8AD9-492047CC1EA6?$format=json&$filter=Business_Accounting_NO eq {}".format(x)).json()
        result.append([JSONContent['Business_Accounting_NO'],
                       JSONContent['Capital_Stock_Amount']])
    except:
        pass

dataset = pd.DataFrame(result)
dataset.head()
```

why result empty?
thanks!!!

Comment: They may have a rate limit, try sleeping between requests.

Comment: added time.sleep(10), no luck, stucked for whole day

Comment: The answer might be in an exception that you catch but are ignoring.

Comment: Did you look at the JSON response? It's a list of dictionaries, not a single dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import requests



listID = ['22555003','12345678','27240313']
#12345678 is error ID
result = []
for x in listID:
    try:
        JSONContent = requests.get("https://data.gcis.nat.gov.tw/od/data/api/5F64D864-61CB-4D0D-8AD9-492047CC1EA6?$format=json&$filter=Business_Accounting_NO eq {}".format(x)).json()
        #print(JSONContent[0]['Business_Accounting_NO'])
        result.append([JSONContent[0]['Business_Accounting_NO'],JSONContent[0]['Capital_Stock_Amount']])
        print(result)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
dataset = pd.DataFrame(result)
dataset.head()
print(result)
```

Comment: savior! why bs4?
one last question, if the column number is huge, how would you approach it?

Comment: can you please elaborate more on this question, what do we mean here by column number?

Comment: you can ignore bs4 that is unused import

Comment: the original api may return a lot of column, for putting here, i selected only 2 column, so if lets say the api will return 50 column, how should one approach such matter?

Comment: i used exception handling and printed the message , from there i got to know that this is list of dictionaries , in this case it was having only one dictionary so i have to use indexing to get 1 dict of list, hence [0] syntax, for getting all the columns you can  use any method to get dictionary key and values .